# Why does a car body ECU module need to share the ground with the circuit it monitors

Tags: wiring, diagram

I am finding difficulty reading a basic wiring diagram from Bentley for my 1996 E36 BMW. I do not understand why the ECU needs to be connected to the ground. I understand that the trunk lights receive power from the ECU, then the electron will flow to the ground if the circuit is closed. But why does the ECU needs to be connected to the ground?

[image: This is the original wiring diagram, and a side by side copy of it with my notes]

Another question is why 2 wires (VIO/BLK) are needed to send power? why not a single wire?

Comment: The Vio/Blk notation means a violet wire with a black stiripe - one wire with two colours, not two wires.  The other wire is brown with a white stripe.

Comment: If the ecu is not connected to ground then it won’t have a completed circuit to the power supply.

Comment: Solar Mike, I understand that, but why that connection should be shared with this particular circuit? I think that as other have pointed it, it is to control this trunk light itself.

Comment: @Solar, see my answer below.

Comment: The ecu will still have an earth connection. Sensing the status of the switch is a needed function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wire 14 is monitoring the status of the switch.

- This can be used to initiate a fade-in / fade-out.
- It may also be used to switch off wire 26 if the trunk is left open for too long. This would protect against running the battery flat.

> Another question is why 2 wires (VIO/BLK) are needed to send power? why not a single wire?

Because the lamps are on the left and right side of the trunk. The second wire (violet with black stripe) jumps from one fitting to the other.

Comment: I understood  that VIO/BLK is just one wire with strips of black. Can you please tell me if the direction of the brown arrows I have drawn on the diagram are right?

Comment: @ZiadElHachem What are the brown arrows meant to signify? Without that, we can't tell you whether they are right or not.

Comment: They are meant to represent the electron flow from + to -

Comment: Forget about electron flow. It will cause you and those with whom you try to communicate much confusion. For a start, electron flow is from - to +. Instead just deal with conventional current from + to -. Your arrows represent conventional current.